# django admin : string index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Following is the traceback for the django admin erorr I am getting. I am able to open all admin pages except this one. I am using django with mongodb.

**Environment**:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/datarepo/production/

Django Version: 2.2.8
Python Version: 3.7.9

```
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'datarepo',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

**Template error**:

```
In template C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 62
   string index out of range
       
    
    52 :             {% endblock %}
       53 :         </div>
       54 :         {% endif %}
       55 :         {% endblock %}
       56 :         {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
       57 :     </div>
       58 :     <!-- END Header -->
       59 :     {% block breadcrumbs %}
       60 :     <div class="breadcrumbs">
       61 :     <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
       62 :     {% if t itle %} &rsaquo; {{  title }}{% endif %}
       63 :     </div>
       64 :     {% endblock %}
       65 :     {% endif %}
       66 : 
       67 :     {% block messages %}
       68 :         {% if messages %}
       69 :         <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
       70 :           <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
       71 :         {% endfor %}</ul>
       72 :         {% endif %}
```

**Traceback**:

```
File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py" in render
  33.         return super().render(context)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in render
  214.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in result_list
  339.         'results': list(results(cl)),

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in results
  315.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in __init__
  306.         super().__init__(*items)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  249.                     result_repr = display_for_field(value, f, empty_value_display)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in display_for_field
  396.         return formats.number_format(value)

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py" in number_format
  183.         use_l10n=use_l10n,

File "C:\Abhi\Office\django\virtualenv1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\numberformat.py" in format
  46.     if str_number[0] == '-':

Exception Type: IndexError at /admin/datarepo/production/
Exception Value: string index out of range
```

Following is my admin.py content :

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db.models import ManyToOneRel, ForeignKey, OneToOneField
    from .models import Production, Event, Mhwellmapping, FilesAdmin
    
    MySpecialAdmin = lambda model: type('SubClass'+model.__name__, (admin.ModelAdmin,), {
        'list_display': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields],
        'list_select_related': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields if isinstance(x, (ManyToOneRel, ForeignKey, OneToOneField,))]
    })
    
    admin.site.unregister(User)
    admin.site.register(User, MySpecialAdmin(User))
    admin.site.register(Production, MySpecialAdmin(Production))
    admin.site.register(Event, MySpecialAdmin(Event))
    admin.site.register(Mhwellmapping, MySpecialAdmin(Mhwellmapping))
    admin.site.register(FilesAdmin, MySpecialAdmin(FilesAdmin))
```

Please tell me what is going wrong here? Thanks.

If in admin.py, I change     admin.site.register(Production, MySpecialAdmin(Production))  to   admin.site.register(Production), then it's working, but I want to show data in tabular format in admin.

Just now I added columns one by one, It worked fine for first 9 columns, than on 10th column in list_display, it showed the same error. Is there any restriction on number of columns in admin? How can I increase the number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I didnot have the column creating problem in some of the documents. So it created problem. Answering this if someone gets this error.

Comment: make ```46.     if str_number[0] == '-':``` into ```if str_number and str_number[0] == '-'``` future proofing

Answer (score 0):

its bcuz of adding a column of model in list_display_links that have an empty value, its probably bcuz you primary key column and list_display_links column are differents.

for fixing it you must be change list_display_links column to primary key column or any column that have null constraint.